# Append text to textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I append a list of text into a textarea?

```
<textarea id="alltext"></textarea>

<ol>
    <li onclick="addText(Hello')">Hello</li>
    <li onclick="addText(World')">World</li>
    <li onclick="addText(Earthlings')">Earthlings</li>
</ol>

<script>
    var Alltext = "";
    function addText(text) {
        Alltext += text
    }
document.getElementById("alltext").value = Alltext;
</script>
```

This is quite inefficient as the list is actually very long. The text added is exactly the value I see on the HTML so there's no need to type it twice right?

Is there any better methods?

Comment: So are you looking for a means to add the text as many here have answered, or are you looking for a means to build the list in code instead of manually?

Comment: the system had the answer for this. Thanks for the time to read!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use event delegation by assigning the `onclick` to the `<ol>`. Then pass the `event` object as the argument, and using that, grab the text from the clicked element.

```js
function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("alltext").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="alltext"></textarea>

<ol onclick="addText(event)">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
  <li>Earthlings</li>
</ol>
```

Note that this method of passing the `event` object works in older IE as well as W3 compliant systems.

Comment: I think this nailed it. Thank you for your kind patience!

Comment: Do you think there is a possibility to add word in the middle of the text?

Answer (score 9):

Give this a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List Test</title>
    <style>
        li:hover {
            cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("li").click(function(){
                $('#alltext').append($(this).text());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>List items</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>World</li>
        <li>Earthlings</li>
    </ol>
    <form>
        <textarea id="alltext"></textarea>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using jQuery for this tiny task would be massive overkill.

Comment: Thanks Carl, but I would prefer not to use jquery.. Thanks a million for your time anyway!

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<button onclick="appendToTextarea()">Append Text</button>

<script>
function appendToTextarea() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
    var newText = "New text to append.";
    textarea. value += newText;
}
</script>
```

when the button is clicked, the appendToTextarea function is called. This function retrieves the textarea element by its ID, appends the new text to its current value, and sets the updated value back to the textarea.