# Turn text into textbox OnClick Edit button

Tags: javascript, html, css

If the user presses the Edit button, the text should turn into a text box with the information still in what the user inputted.Can u help me with the code in HTML,CSS & Javascript.

Comment: Post what have you done with your code

Comment: Check this link of [the system][1] answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14445052

Answer (score 0):

Basically somewhat like this, just add `readonly` attribute in the `textarea`:

```js
$('#edit').click(function(){
    $('#text').removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

```css
#text{border:none;resize:none;font-family:Arial;width:400px;height:200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="edit">Edit</button>
<br/>
<textarea id='text' readonly>
    SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT
</textarea>
```

Comment: I want to edit the contents of table onclick edit button.Can you please make it instead of textarea...

Answer (score -2):

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtBox.Text = // Value of what the user typed before editing
}``
```

Comment: He didn't ask for C# .NET code. He asked for JS code.