# Clickable list element added to text area

Tags: javascript, list, onclick, textarea, element

After viewing [Append text to textarea with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444938/append-text-to-textarea-with-javascript) I am looking for a way to insert line breaks so that each item that is clicked on shows up on then next line in the text area. Is this possible?

Comment: `function addText(text) {  Alltext += text + "\r\n";   }` or, if `"\r\n"` does not work, try `"<br/>"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from the link that you shared, you could do something like this:

```
<textarea id="alltext"></textarea>

<ol onclick="addText(event)">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
  <li>Earthlings</li>
</ol>

<script>
  function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    targ = targ.textContent + '\r\n' || targ.innerText + '\r\n';
    document.getElementById("alltext").value += targ;
  }
</script>
```