# Appending text into single text area - separating by paragraph (using javascript)

Tags: javascript

I found this answer already that helped, but does not answer this question: [Append text to textarea with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444938/append-text-to-textarea-with-javascript)

To borrow from that as an example:
Clicking **all three** of the list items below, would read "HelloWorldEarthlings"

```
<textarea id="alltext"></textarea>
<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>World</li>
<li>Earthlings</li>
</ol>
<script>
function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("alltext").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;
}
</script>
```

I'd like to add a list and then distinguish clicks from each list into their own paragraph,

**For example, I'd like to click the first option on each list below:**

```
<textarea id="alltext"></textarea>
<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Greetings</li>
<li>Salutations</li>
</ol>

<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Humans!</li>
<li>Peasants?</li>
<li>Earthlings.</li>
</ol>
<script>
function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("alltext").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;
}
</script>
```

**To somehow print:**

Hello

Humans!

edit:  I'd like to put upwards of ten lists - not just two.

Comment: By paragraph do you mean Text paragraph, or separated by a paragraph tag? Right now `alltext` is a textarea, so you would have to change that to another container if you want to use html tags on the content within it.

Comment: `document.getElementById("alltext").value += String.fromCharCode(10) + ( targ.textContent || targ.innerText);` You might want to have two line breaks in which case you would just use `String.fromCharCode(10)` twice.

Comment: What other container could I change it to, and how?

Comment: If it doesn't need to be a textarea you could append `p` tags to a `div` and get actual paragraphs.

Comment: Adam H - I'd like to have just a blank document with the actual paragraphs, I don't need (or want) any visible html or anything.  How would I do what you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I've taken a slightly different approach than others used here. I've elected to do everything at run-time, so you don't have to pre-calc anything. Just throw your data into the page and it should 'just work' tm.

I saw you wanted o have an arbitrary number of lists, so allowed for that. Also, presumably, you'd like an arbitrary number of options in each list. What is uncertain however, is what the expected long-term behaviour of such a control would be. I.e if I have two lists, can I only evr expect to see two words in the box, or will it just continue to append the most recently chosen one ad-infinitum?

So, when the page loads I quickly examine the page's contents, looking for and counting instances of `<OL>` elements. I then create an array with this many elements before setting an attribute of each list to tell the list what it's index is.

When an `<li>` is clicked, the word is retrieved, the index of the list in which it resides is retrieved and then the word is stuffed into the array we created earlier. We then ask for a re-draw, in which case all of the elements of the array are stuck together with a space(' ') in between each element, before it's blasted to the screen.

```js
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
window.addEventListener('load', onWindowLoaded, false);

var wordArray;

function onWindowLoaded(evt)
{
 var orderedLists = document.querySelectorAll('ol');
 var listArray = [...orderedLists];
 wordArray = new Array(listArray.length);
 
 listArray.forEach( function(curList, index)
      {
       curList.dataset.listIndex = index;
       curList.addEventListener('click', onListClicked, false);
      }
     );
}

function onListClicked(evt)
{
 var text = evt.target.textContent;
 var arrayIndex = parseInt(this.dataset.listIndex);
 wordArray[arrayIndex] = text;
 renderText();
}

function renderText()
{
 var str = wordArray.join(" ");
 byId('output').textContent = str;
}
```

```html
 <textarea id='output'></textarea>
 <ol>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Greetings</li>
  <li>Salutations</li>
 </ol>
 <ol>
  <li>Humans</li>
  <li>Peasants</li>
  <li>Earthlings</li>
 </ol>
```

Comment: I really like your approach, however; I think OP wanted a running list of the actions taken, should be really easy to update your solution to handle that.

Comment: Actually - I like that this seems to handle only one response from each list.  How would you do what @Adam H did with inserting 2 line breaks after each one?

Comment: @Ryan'sDad - it's actually surprisingly easy. Just change `wordArray.join(" ");` into `wordArray.join("\n\n");` This way, we join each of the array members together with a pair of new-lines, instead of a single space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want text paragraphs:

```
document.getElementById("alltext").value += "\t" + (targ.textContent || targ.innerText) + "\n";
```

```html
<textarea id="alltext"></textarea>
<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Greetings</li>
<li>Salutations</li>
</ol>

<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Humans!</li>
<li>Peasants?</li>
<li>Earthlings.</li>
</ol>
<script>
function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("alltext").value += "\t" + (targ.textContent || targ.innerText) + "\n";
}
</script>
```

If you want HTML Paragraphs you can change the `alltext` `textarea` to a `div`, and use the following code:

```
document.getElementById("alltext").innerHTML += "<p>" + (targ.textContent || targ.innerText) + "</p>";
```

```html
<div id="alltext"></div>
<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Greetings</li>
<li>Salutations</li>
</ol>

<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Humans!</li>
<li>Peasants?</li>
<li>Earthlings.</li>
</ol>
<script>
function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("alltext").innerHTML += "<p>" + (targ.textContent || targ.innerText) + "</p>";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of possible solutions, you can pick which one you like best.

Append all to a single textarea with line breaks:

```js
function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("alltext").value += String.fromCharCode(10) + String.fromCharCode(10) +  (targ.textContent || targ.innerText);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="alltext"></textarea>
<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Greetings</li>
<li>Salutations</li>
</ol>

<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Humans!</li>
<li>Peasants?</li>
<li>Earthlings.</li>
</ol>
```

Append P tags to a Div:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('alltext');

function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var p = document.createElement('p')
    p.innerText = targ.textContent || targ.innerText;
    container.append(p);
}
```

```html
<p id="alltext"></p>
<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Greetings</li>
<li>Salutations</li>
</ol>

<ol onclick="addText(event)">
<li>Humans!</li>
<li>Peasants?</li>
<li>Earthlings.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I really like the first option - but is it possible to add a second line break so that it looks more like the second example?  Thank you so much!