# Add text in Textarea and keep the previus

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea I would like to add a text in it with a js script and keep the text already existing.

Basically, I just want to input a custom message into an email.
The custom message that i want to add contain new lines.

I tried this it remove all previus text

> document.getElementsByName('txtbdy')[0].value = "test";

```
<textarea name="txtbdy" title="Corps du message" rows="19" cols="104" onchange="onChgBdy();"></textarea>
```

Comment: So you want `document.getElementsByName('txtbdy')[0].value += "test";`?

Comment: i would like to keep the previus text in the field and add new one who look like "Hello dear Sir
thank you for your email 
%NEW LINE %
Well done
%NEW LINE %
Best regards"

Comment: Then what's the issue with the code I posted above?

Comment: that pretty much does what you need

Comment: replace the %NEW LINE % with real new line, actualy if i try do add anything with new line nothing happening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append text to textarea with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444938/append-text-to-textarea-with-javascript)

Comment: "document.getElementsByName('txtbdy')[0].value = "test";" 
replace whole field with new text. 

I need to keep the text already in it, just add new one

Comment: hello, sorry no or maybe i wrote something wrong ?

Comment: you do know there is a difference between `document.getElementsByName('txtbdy')[0].value = "test"` and `document.getElementsByName('txtbdy')[0].value += "test"` right?

Comment: i tried "document.getElementsByName('txtbdy')[0].value += "test""
nothing happening. on outlook live light version,

Comment: this seem to work "let email_input = document.getElementsByName('txtbdy');
email_input[0].focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'sample@email.com');"


bot how can i add new lines to the text ?

Comment: try this document.getElementsByName('txtbdy')[0].value += "\n Hello dear Sir \n thank you for your email \n Well done  \n Best regards"

Comment: Hi thank you, it worked but the new text goes to the end, it suppose to go in first and old message after we are close ))) do you know how i can reverse ? have it in first place and old text later